# Change the arg_separator.output separator directive in php.ini

Tags: apache, php, directive

Can anybody tell me what happen if i change the arg_separator.input  directive in php.ini file and set it to 'a' and my form have two text fileds named  "name and age" . Then if i submit it then url will be like www.yourdomain.com?name=tempaage=12  did this confuse the server or it will run fine. Is there any rule to have only specific character as arg separator.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?! also if you had somone enter a long string of aaaaaaaaa they would each become a parameter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then if i submit it then url will be like
>   www.yourdomain.com?name=tempaage=12

What makes you say that the browser will send such a string to the server? It won't, it will simply use `&` as the separator [as suggested here](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#form-content-type). If you plan to generate URLs yourself, try encoding your example data like this:

```
www.yourdomain.com?n%61me=tempa%61ge=12
```